# Can't update or uninstall built-in Whatsapp

Tags: updates, whatsapp-messenger, uninstallation

I have an iBall Slide 3G 7334i tab which has a built-in `Whatsapp v.2.9.5196` which has provision to <kbd>Force Stop</kbd> and <kbd>Disable</kbd> but not <kbd>Uninstall</kbd>. I can't either `uninstall` or `update` and the message:

> "Your phone date is inaccurate.Adjust your clock and try again"

keeps on coming.

I have searched all over and I can't get the remedy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to uninstall and reinstall latest version of WhatsApp. It will fix your issue.
Since your phone have built-in WhatsApp Application(system app) you can't normally uninstall your App.

Try to uninstall using [Debloater](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-bloatware-android-without-rooting/) which helps to remove a built-in App without root.

After uninstalling try to install a latest version of WhatsApp APK file from [here](https://www.roidbay.com/app/apk/com.whatsapp/)

[Source](https://www.roidbay.com/blog/guide/fixed-phone-date-inaccurate-whatsapp/)